# Why can i not use glue (which contains cyklohexane, petrol and ethyl acetate) for gluing PVC materials?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, polymers, petrochemistry

The manufacturer do not recommend using glue to gluing PVC. But Why? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Always write clear questions with included relevant details, purpose, context or background info to receive useful answers. Otherwise the answers may be just guesses. // With comparable lengths of the question title and body, the former is too long and the latter too short.

Comment: Which sort of glue ? There are a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, PVC is supposed be glued only by glues explicitly intended for PVC glueing.

Otherwise, the glue solvent may not prepare PVC surface for glueing sufficiently and the glue residue after solvent evaporation may not be PVC compatible to form reliable binding.